# Does the Raspberry Pi 4's processor support ARM's SHA256 instructions?

Tags: pi-4, assembly, cryptocurrency, encryption

According to Wikipedia, every Armv8 processor should support sha256 hashing instructions however **/proc/cpuinfo** doesn't list it. Could there be a failure to identify the feature by the kernel?

```
processor   : 3
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3
```

Comment: Please provide ***references***: a link to the Wikipedia article, and what is the source of the info in your code block???????

Comment: at a guess, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARMv8 and `/proc/cpuinfo' :p

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, the reason why /proc/cpuinfo doesn't show sha256 support is that ARM Holdings would require a large fee to permit Rpi foundation to include those instructions in the CPU. They didn't pay for them.

Comment: A reference for this would be nice, even if it is just a link to a discussion somewhere else.

Comment: I thought only intel would do such cruel things as selling you CPUs with hardware features built in and hide overclocking and AVX512 behind a pay-wall.  

But well BMW sells you a car with all bells and whistles only to require a monthly fee to enable seat-heating and other comfort features.  

And I won't start with Adobe and PANTONE here.  

Anyway. I see where this is heading…